# Changes to the code - I do not see on the site

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-3, opencart2.3

Got a question. For example, I change the code on the page

> /catalog/view/theme/nextdef/template/extension/module/latest.twig

, or rather add a handler to the button:

```
<i class = "fa fa-heart" onclick = "window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push ({'event': 'heart'}); "> </i> </button>
```

But when you click on this element, there are no changes. If you look at the page code, then it is also not updated. Although I write the cache and update the Disable cache inside the browser too, and still no changes ... I would be grateful if you help. thank

Comment: Make sure cache is disabled from dashboard upper-right gear button, as well click on refresh button from "extension -> modification" page after changes in file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the template editor had a history of this page. And there was no code. Apparently, he referred to her. I did not know that opencart prioritizes history compared to server files.